# How to send request to third party application after approval of request?

Tags: workflow, servicenow

I am trying to call the third party application using script in service now workflow.When someone request a item from service now catalog It goes for approval to admin.Once admin approves the request incident status is approved.But before ending the workflow I want to run script to call some third party application API and do some task using script.

- My first question is : is this possible to call third party app from workflow script?
- Second Question : can someone please guide me how to call third party app if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflow uses scripts the same as any other part of ServiceNow, so

1. Yes, you can call third party apps
2. Unless you specify what kind of integration you would like and with which application, the only thing I can do is point you in the direction of [the official documentation](https://docs.servicenow.com/integrate/concept/c_IntegrateWThirdPartyAppsDataSrces.html). It provides with everything you need to know.

Comment: Thank you so much.Document is really very helpful.Thanks a lot for helping me out.